# How to combine Daterangepicker's daterange-btn and Datatable to show results that match Daterangepicker's parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, daterangepicker

As the title says, I am trying to, when the page loads for the first time, show all the information from a MYSQL table in a datatable. However, once the page is loaded, the user has the chance to set a daterange with "daterangepicker" plugin. If a daterange is picked, I want to pass the daterange selected in $_GET variables. I have researched about this topic but there seems to be little information about it. The big problem here is that I don't know how/where to show the results that match the daterange picked. My thought is that where the $.ajax is set, bring out the info. Please correct me or give me any feedback! It would truly be appreciated.

```
$('#daterange-btn').daterangepicker(

 {
  ranges   : {
    'Hoy'       : [moment(), moment()],
    'Últimos 7 días' : [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
    'Últimos 30 días': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
    'Este mes'  : [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')]
  },
  startDate: moment(),
  endDate  : moment()
 },
  function (start, end) {

  $('#daterange-btn span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
   var fechaInicial = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   $(".fechaInicial").val(fechaInicial);
   $(".fechaFinal").val(fechaFinal);
   var fechaFinal = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   var capturarRango = $("#daterange-btn span").html();
   localStorage.setItem("capturarRango", capturarRango);

   $.ajax({
    url:"ajax/datatable-adminventas.ajax.php",
    type:"get",
    data:{fechaInicial: fechaInicial, fechaFinal: fechaFinal},
    success:function(respuesta){
      console.log(respuesta);
      $('.tablaAdminVentas').DataTable({
          "ajax": "ajax/datatable-adminventas.ajax.php",
          "deferRender": true,
          "retrieve": true,
          "processing": true,
          "language": {
            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
            "sUrl":            "",
            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primero",
            "sLast":     "Último",
            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
              "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
              "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        }
      });
    }
  });
 }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the same API twice as you are doing above.

Here's how you can do

Datepicker change event. This is just to make event function clear.

You can use your `function (start, end) {` function if it works

```
$('#daterange').daterangepicker();

// Triggered when the picker is hidden on date selection
$('#daterange').on('hide.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    var fechaInicial = picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var fechaFinal = picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    refreshGrid(fechaInicial, fechaFinal);
});
```

More daterangepicker events [here](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#events)

`Datatable` load logic code where we pass selected Dates.

I assume your Datatable code added in question is loading table properly.

Pls see the `ajax part of the code`

```
function refreshGrid(start, end){

    $('.tablaAdminVentas').DataTable({
      "ajax": {
        "url": "ajax/datatable-adminventas.ajax.php",
        "type": "GET",
        "data": {fechaInicial: start, fechaFinal: end},
      },
      "deferRender": true,
          "retrieve": true,
          "processing": true,
          "language": {
            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
            "sUrl":            "",
            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primero",
            "sLast":     "Último",
            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
              "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
              "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Hey @MyTwoCents , thank you fof the answer! I have been testing out the code but it doesn't work for me, since I can do the request once, but when changing the daterange, it doesn't call the funciton again to bring the new data. Got skype or a way to show you what I am doing? Thank you for your kindness and willingness to help! – Oscar Paredez 6 mins ago

Comment: Plus, another thing. I would like to, as soon as the page loads, show rows that contain the date of today. Is there a way to do this?